# Database design - limiting linked records

Tags: database-design, ms-access-2007, relationship

Currently I have a database with the following relationships:

One Client has multiple Entities (via Client Name - this is unique)

One Entity has multiple EntityServices (via Entity ID)

One Service has multiple EntityServices (via Service Name - basically a table of service lines)

Now this is all working fine, but I want to create a table by the name of EngagementLetters. It should have the following relationships:

One Client has multiple EngagementLetters (via Client Name)

One EngagementLetters has multiple EntityServices (via Engagement Letter ID)

and the tricky one: all EntityServices under a single EngagementLetter must have the same Client

I've been able to create the above except for the last point. It's stumped me, I have no idea how to do it! Would anyone be able to help with this?

Cheers,

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      Client
     ^      ^
     |      |
     |      Entities   Service
     Eletter      ^          ^
        ^         |          |
        |_______ EntityServices
```

Like this?

"One Client has multiple EngagementLetters (via Client Name - this is unique)"

why Client Name? you used Client Id for the relationship with entity. It is fine to make client name unique, but it is not good practice to use a different key for different relationships. Foreign keys should typically point to the primary key (which i presume is client id?)

"and the tricky one: all EntityServices under a single EngagementLetter must have the same Client"

What do you mean? Is there a relationship between EntityServices and client? there is one via Entities, do you mean the client id derived from the related entities parent row? Is this in some way related to the client linked to by engagement letter?

If you simply want to enforce the rule as you state it, you should consider creating a new table that links to both client and engagement letter, and link to there from entity services. However this is only a good choice if you can make the case that the client/engagement letter combination is some kind of object - not just an abstract construct to implement this particular business rule.

If it's just that, a business rule, then you should use triggers or application logic to enforce it, and reserve foreign keys only for representing relationships between data structures.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes the diagram you drew up is correct.  Sorry I made a bit of a mistake - I've actually only used Client Name for the relevant relationships.

There is no direct relationship between EntityServices and Client, but there is an association as an Entity is linked to a single Client, and an EntityService is linked to a single Entity, so an EntityService is indirectly linked to a single Client.

Likewise, a single EntityService is indirectly linked to a single Client (each EntityService is linked to one EngagementLetter, and each EngagementLetter is linked to one Client).

Comment: Sorry about the bad breaks - still figuring out Stackoverflow's format!

Comment: @andrewb, seems you repeated yourself: "so an EntityService is indirectly linked to a single Client", "Likewise, a single EntityService is indirectly linked to a single Client". My question is, should the client that is indirectly linked from entityservices via entity be identical to the client indirectly linked from entityservices via engagementletter? If so you could consider giving  both entities and eletter a composite key that contains client name and give entityservices a single client name which points to these two.

Comment: Yes that's correct - the EntityService should be linked to the same Client through both the EngagementLetter and the Entity.  I'll give your suggestion a go, thanks.

Comment: I've only just had a chance to attempt this as I haven't been at work.  I have FKClient in tblEntity and tblEngagementLetter - is that what you mean by "composite"?  Also I'm not sure what you mean by "give entityservices a single client name which points to these two".  I already have a relationship between Entity and EntityService, and EngagementLetter and EntityService.

Comment: I've posted a picture of my current structure here:
http://www.accessforums.net/attachment.php?attachmentid=6850&d=1332462761

Comment: @andrewb, I can't see the picture - login required. Try imagebin. "Composite" means the key consists of more than one column. So my idea is to give both engagement letter and entity a composite key consisting of client name plus some other column that makes the row unique (for that client). Lets call them Engagement Letter Number and Entity Number respectively. Then in entity services, you'd have Client Name, Entity Number, Engagement Letter Number (and of course service id too).

Comment: Hopefully this works: http://imagebin.org/205310.  What you described sounds much like what I have, though on Access only one field is selected as a primary key.  I can't see a way that I can select multiple fields.

Comment: Well, you should be able to make composite keys. Obviously you can't include an autoincrementing column in such a key.

Comment: Awesome, I've sorted it out.  I've created composite keys on the tables as you advised.  I also made the relationship between tblEntity and tblEntityServices link both EntityName and ClientName.  I did likewise with the relationship between tblEngagementLetter and tblEntityServices.  Thanks for your patience and help, think I've now got a much better understanding of composite keys and indexes.  Now I can implement business rules like I ought to be able to!

Comment: @andrewb: ok, glad that helped. Good luck with your project :)

Comment: Unfortunately I've run into an issue with this solution - I can't change the Client Name if any Services have been entered.  It says "cannot perform cascading operation - there must be a related record in 'Entities'".  All my relationships have the cascade update option, but it seems like it may be attempting it in the wrong order.  Any advice?

Comment: Personally I would never use ClientName as primary key. Rather I'd create a surrogate key, Client Id, and use that. Obviously you would still have the Client Name column to store the client's name, you just wouldn't use that as key.

Comment: Yeah I've been thinking about it since I was last in work and I came to the same conclusion.  That way the primary key doesn't every change.  Cheers.  Also, services are entered via a subform in the engagement letter form, so there's no need for users to ever see the primary key.  I'll just need to make sure that it still sorts by client name as users cycle through form records.  Thanks again for the help.